# Python Django сохранить словарь в бд

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли в Django:
Есть словарь, состоит из  key = название столбца item = значение
Как сохранить в бд?
спасибо.

Comment: Значение это int и char.У меня есть форма, которая получает данные, далее функция обрабатывает данные получается словарь {название столбца: значение }.

Comment: Дело в том, что хочу универсальную функцию, которую можно использовать в будущем c  другими таблицами

Comment: у баз есть поле данных типо `json`, это и есть ваш словарь

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Answer (score 0):

Верный ответ:

```py
d = {'k':'i','1k':'1i','2k':'2i'}
NameModel.objects.create(**d)
```